# Opening the different's app activity

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions, root

There's an app called *X* and an activity *Z* in the *Y* app. X can open activity Z only if it has `exported` parameter set to `true` in Manifest. If it doesn't, I get a permission denial exception. Okay, it's understandable.

So I try to open activity Z from the X app using `Process.execute` and the `am start com.package.name/.activity` command. The command works perfect when typed in `adb shell` on my computer. However, `Process.execute` even with *su* permissions doesn't open the activity. But the output is correct ("Starting blah blah blah").

Do you have any idea how to open the Z activity from the X app? I cannot modify the Y app - it's not made by me.

Comment: If the developers of app Y wanted you to be able to open activity Z directly, they would have exported it.

Comment: To be clear - I want to open Instagram's taking photo activity. The purpose is as simple as the app I'm trying to implement this feature to - to let users take an Instagram photo without having to open the app. There's nothing wrong with it, it doesn't even violate Instagram's ToS. But I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: If Instagram wanted you to be able to open the "taking photo activity", they would have exported it and documented how to invoke it on their Web site. They didn't, at least not to date. Hence, Instagram can get rid of this activity, move it to a new name/package, etc. without notice, breaking your app, even if you could get this working.

Comment: Yes, I know the risk. But in a few lines of code I can check if the  app is installed and if it contains this activity. I'm sure there's a way to open the activity. I just can't come up with a workaround.